# RandomNumberGenerator vs RNGCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, random, cryptography

According to MSDN documentation for [RandomNumberGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator%28v=VS.71%29.aspx):

> Application code does not directly use this class. This abstract class is provided as the base class for all cryptographic random number generators.
>
> For an implementation of a cryptographic random number generator, use the derived class RNGCryptoServiceProvider.

However, I have seen the following code used on a few occassions in different code bases:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[...];
RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
rng.GetBytes(bytes);
```

Most notably with [StackExchange](http://code.google.com/p/stackid/source/browse/OpenIdProvider/Current.cs#1135) (which I assume includes SO) and also with [BCrypt.Net](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1eef0262901c#BCrypt.Net/BCrypt.cs).

Therefore, I am a little confused - what type of `RandomNumberGenerator` is the above code returning? Also is it a bit of a flaw that some code bases *are* using `RandomNumberGenerator` rather than `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`?

I assume `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` is doing under the hood which I am completely missing here, but technically (as it's an abstract class) shouldn't the above code throw an error?

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the RNGCryptoServiceProvider class is now obsolete and the use of the RandomNumberGenerator static methods is instead recommended.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` method calls `RandomNumberGenerator.Create("System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator")`, which will eventually create an instance of `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.

(It does some lookups in a pair of dictionaries, so it's likely that you can change the behaviour of that call by registering a default random generator somewhere.)

The actual type of the object returned is not known at compile time, it's only known that it will inherit the `RandomNumberGenerator` class, so you can use a `RandomNumberGenerator` reference variable for it.

This way of creating different types of instances depending on the input is used in a couple of places in the framework, for example by the `WebRequest.Create` method.

---

Someone at Micrsoft has "fixed" the current documentation (framework 4.5) for the `Create()` method. It now says:

> "When overridden in a derived class, creates an instance of the
>   default implementation of a cryptographic random number generator that
>   can be used to generate random data."

The documentation for framework 4.0 says:

> "Creates an instance of the default implementation of a cryptographic
>   random number generator that can be used to generate random data."

This is the correct description of what the method does. I will put in a request to put that description back in the newer documentation.

Comment: "*which will eventually create an instance of `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`*" - What is the criteria for this though? Why not `AesCryptoServiceProvider`/`SHA512`/`DAS` etc. specifically? Is it just the same approach with `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` that `RandomNumberGenerator` has i.e. does that internally decide on which algorithm it will use under the hood?

Comment: @James: Well, basically it is because that's the only random number generator that is implemented by default (see the inheritance hierarchy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42ks8fz1). `AesCryptuServiceProvider` is an encryption algorithm, not a random number generator. The random number generator isn't specific for different encryption algorithms. The only reason to make it possible to register a different generator, is that someone might find that the current implementation doesn't produce good enough random numbers.

Comment: D'oh, that was my mistake, assuming all `CryptoServiceProvider`'s were RNG's! So realistically there is only one implementation of an RNG part of the framework and it's `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`, therefore, it doesn't matter which one I use?

Comment: @James: With what's currently known, the default RNG is the best option. the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` may be replaced by a different implementation in future frameworks, and then the `Create()` method will return that instead. If the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is found to be too weak, you might want to create a specific provider instead, but there is nothing that you can do about that now, so using the `Create()` method is the most future proof solution.

Comment: Is `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` thread-safe?

Comment: As of .NET Core 6, `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is marked as obsolete (so shouldn't be explicitly instantiated).  `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` appears to be the 'official' way to get an RNG, with the object being returned displayed as a `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGeneratorImplementation`.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `RandomNumberGenerator` is basically messed up. As another example, there's documentation like this:

> When overridden in a derived class, creates an instance of the specified implementation of a cryptographic random number generator.

... for a static method. Static methods *can't* be overridden. Whoever wrote the documentation clearly wasn't thinking straight.

I suspect the original intention was something like:

> Application code does not directly **instantiate** this class. This abstract class is provided as the base class for all cryptographic random number generators.

I think the code you've posted (using the static `Create` method) is entirely reasonable. It's the same sort of pattern as is used for `XmlReader.Create` etc - the static method chooses the most appropriate implementation.

Comment: "*the static method chooses the most appropriate implementation*" - it's a bit frustrating that there is no documentation indicating the criteria for what version *is* the most appropriate though.

Answer (score 2):

`RandomNumberGenerator.Create` is a static factory method. Surely it will return an instances of a *derived* class. And that one is not abstract so all of this is legal.

Abstract classes are *made* to be used everywhere instead of using a more concrete class. They are meant to be a versioning-friendly interface.

Comment: "*Surely it will return an instance of a derived class*" - I would imagine it is, however, it's not clear from the documentation what version it is returning.

Comment: The actual type returned can vary. You can override it in the web.config (don't have the reference at hand, but both my memory and Reflector say this is the case). There are no guarantees about the return type. Does the concrete type matter for you?

Comment: "*does the concrete type matter for you*" - For what I am using it for probably not as all I need is for it to generate a secure random number. However, I was curious as to why the documentation was quoting stuff like "*Application code does not directly use this class*" when it's clearly not the case. From the answers posted it does appear that it's a bug in the documentation.

Comment: I agree. It is a documentation flaw.

Comment: Just to clarify your point, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.randomnumbergenerator(v=vs.71)) does state "*You cannot create an instance of an abstract class. Application code will create a new instance of a derived class.*". However, my question was guided more towards what *type* of derived class it would create.

Comment: Is `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` thread-safe?

Comment: @variable Yes. In .NET, static methods generally are thread-safe, and so in this particular case. It would be very hard for different application components and libraries to synchronize access to static methods. They kind of must be thread-safe.