# C#'s Random producing recognisable pattern when using sequential seeds

Tags: c#, random

Given the following:

```
for(int seed = 0; seed < 100; seed++) {
    var random = new Random(seed);
    var roll = (random.Next() % 6) + 1;
    Console.Write(roll + " ");
}
```

I'm seeing a clear pattern in the output:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
```

I do understand that recreating a new `Random` object every time with a sequential seed isn't the "proper" way of using the class, and that strictly speaking I should be keep the `Random` instance around, calling `Next()` on it each time.

However, my use case is that I need to be able to exit my program and restore the state at any moment, and continue the sequence of numbers.

I also need the user to be able to set a seed manually, so I was hoping to be able to do something like:

```
var random = new Random(userSeed + nextValueIndex);
var chosenValue = random.Next();
```

I've also tried `random.Next(min, max)`, and it gives different results, but also in a clear pattern.

Clearly my approach isn't the right way to use the `Random` class, but what is, for my use case?

I understand that random number generation is a very complex topic, so while I'm sort of interested in an explanation of why this is happening, I'm most interested in a practical (easy?) solution ;-)

Comment: You can always check out Random.org https://www.random.org/  As far us user seeding, though - you know how it is when you let users do things... :)

Comment: You can serialize your instance of the random class and deserialize it when your program restarts to continue where it left off.

Comment: Pretty unclear why you *need* a solution, using a seed just once and it will be pleasantly random afterwards.

Comment: Not sure what your actual requirements for the random sequence, but Random not cryptographically random.  There are a few in the framework.  Here's a relevant question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329760/randomnumbergenerator-vs-rngcryptoserviceprovider just fyi

Comment: My use case is that it's the runtime for a [game scripting language](http://www.github.com/inkle/ink). I am creating a built in `RANDOM(min,max)` function for the language, and want users to also be able to call `SEED_RANDOM(seed)`. I've been serialising to a custom JSON format, and haven't been using C#'s own serialisation so far, and would rather not if possible! (Especially since I want to write the code in such a way that's easy to port to other languages.)

Comment: it sounds like you just need to save the (last?) seed used and maybe how many times Next was called (?)

Comment: Keep in mind that the Random class, from the MS doc, says "Pseudo-random numbers are chosen with equal probability from a finite set of numbers. The chosen numbers are not completely random because a mathematical algorithm is used to select them, but they are sufficiently random for practical purposes." If you are looking for a truer random number set, you might want to investigate RNGCryptoServiceProvider though I'm not sure that will fit your needs.

Comment: Just to reinforce Plutonix’s comment.   I have needed to do what you are doing for many reasons.  Think about the following modifications.   A:  Take the var random = new Random(seed) to outside of the loop.    B:  Do not start the seed with 0.  Try a big number like a 7 digit phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, which seems to work nicely. Rather than seeding `Random` with `userSeed + index` (where `index` counts from zero), I simply cache the exact result from `Random` as `previousRandom`, and then seed with `userSeed + previousRandom`. That way, I get nice big numbers as the seed, and it avoids the sequential pattern. (`previousRandom` is initialised as zero, but that's not a problem.)

So, this is roughly what my code looks like:

```
var nextSeed = userSeed + this.previousRandom;
var randomObj = new Random(nextSeed);

var nextRandomValue = randomObj.Next ();
var chosenValue = (nextRandomValue % randomRange) + rangeMin;

this.previousRandom = nextRandomValue;

return chosenValue;
```

The one remaining thing I should probably do is make sure that `userSeed + previousRandom` doesn't overflow (or overflows predictably), because `previousRandom` might get very close to `int`'s upper bound (up to whatever range I allow for `userSeed`).